# Can に have the same function as として?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

In this sentence:

> 君は選ばれたのだ　私の退屈を埋めるための欠片の１つ**に**

Does the particle に work in the same way as として? Is it the same as 私の退屈を埋めるための欠片の１つとして ?

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, に works like English "as", a role marker. "You were chosen **as** one of the pieces...".

- [に to indicate the role you want something to play?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65432/5010)
- [Exact meaning of 教科書をトピックに選ぶ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13896/5010)
- [I really can't understand the use of に + と USED TOGETHER in this clause](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76801/5010)
- [Meaning of にと思って in a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55453/5010)
- [What is the function of the に in 仕上げに?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80057/5010)

> Is it the same as 私の退屈を埋めるための欠片の１つとして?

Yes, at least in your case, に is interchangeable with として. (Of course this is not always true because both として and に have many other functions.)