# 自殺に見せ掛ける - Particle に

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

Context: https://streamable.com/sk6rst

Sentence: 単なる自殺か？ 自殺に見せ掛けた　他殺か？

Question: What is the function of the particle に in 自殺に見せ掛けた ?

Answer (score 3):

AをBに見せ掛ける means "to make A appear to be B", "to pretend A is B", "to show A as B", etc. Grammatically, this に is either "to; into" (resultant state marker) or "as" ([role marker](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/82916/5010)), but basically this particle choice is something you have to memorize along with the verb 見せ掛ける itself.

> 他殺を自殺に見せ掛ける
> to make a murder look like a suicide

> 自殺に見せ掛けた他殺 (relative clause)
> a murder which someone made to look like a suicide
> a murder disguised as a suicide

Comment: I always thought it was と見せ掛けて. Is this wrong? or is there a different meaning?

Comment: @zeuswife と見せ掛ける takes a clause (e.g., 寝ていると見せ掛ける), and に見せ掛ける takes a noun.