# Is this the use of には in this scentence natural?

Tags: grammar, meaning, syntax, sentence

> 立憲君主制を取るヴェレンシア国では、王族は政治家ではなく、外交官としての役割を期待される。諸外国に外遊し、自国のイメージを高め、商品や技術を高く売るのが王族の仕事だ。ヴァレンシア国のスポークスマンと言ってもいい。
> そのため、王族の子女の世話をする保母や従者**には、ネイティブの外国人が二年の任期でつく**。王子、または王女が、公用語であるヴェレンシア語とドイツ語が話せるようになる三歳から十七歳で成人するまでの十五年間、ずっとそれが繰り返される。

The heroin here is from a country where royalty job is to be "salarymen" of their country,basically thus they have educators every two years who are natives of other countries  . What baffles me is that the sentence 保母や従者には、ネイティブの外国人が二年の任期でつく syntax is a little strange to my eyes , is it natural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is a natural sentence. If it's に that threw you off, note that it is a [role marker](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/82916/5010) (*as/for*) here.

> 王族の子女の世話をする保母や従者には、ネイティブの外国人が二年の任期でつく。
> As babysitters or attendants to care for the royal children, native foreigners serve for a two-year term.

Comment: The verb being 就く, this に could be understood in a more straightforward way.