# What does 察するに and 証拠に mean?

Tags: meaning, particle-に

At the start of sentences I found these words **察するに** and **証拠に**

> 察するに私の読者や担当編集が必死になって書け書け言ってくれるあれのことだろう？

I thought that it was related to [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29418/what-does-the-%E3%81%AB-do-in-%E8%A1%A8%E6%83%85%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E5%AF%9F%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB), since I think that it can replace に with と、

> 証拠に、私は君が初めて書いた作品を知っているぞ

But I am not so sure about this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 察するに means "Judging from the situation" or "If I guess". This 証拠に means "As an evidence". These に's are grammatically different.

The first に is a literary conjunctive particle which roughly works like と, but with only a small set of verbs. It directly takes the dictionary form of a **verb**:

- [What does the に do in 表情から察するに?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29418/5010)
- [Grammar behind 言うには](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82426/5010)

The second に is a case particle used as a **role/function** marker. It takes a **noun** (including a verb nominalized with の):

- [に to indicate the role you want something to play?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65432/5010)
- [Exact meaning of 教科書をトピックに選ぶ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13896/5010)
- [I really can't understand the use of に + と USED TOGETHER in this clause](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76801/5010)
- [Meaning of にと思って in a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55453/5010)
- [What is the function of the に in 仕上げに?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80057/5010)